# How to use wget with multithread and wildcards?

Tags: linux, bash, wget

I want to use wget to download multiple files at once in a script using wildcards, like this:

```
wget -r -nd --no-parent --no-remove-listing $ftpUrl -l1 -A file1*.txt &
wget -r -nd --no-parent --no-remove-listing $ftpUrl -l1 -A file2*.txt &
wget -r -nd --no-parent --no-remove-listing $ftpUrl -l1 -A file3*.txt &
```

The problem is that wget downloads .listing file everytime and because there are multiple instances running, sometimes the file is being downloaded when another instance is reading it.

Is there a way to lock .listing file or ask wget to not download it (I can do it manually as the first command)? I don't understand how it reads this .listing file since it's not a plain list of the URLs, but rather something like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x    3 4015     4015        16384 Dec 14 21:23 .
drwxr-xr-x    4 4015     4015         4096 Dec 14 21:23 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 4015     4015          327 Feb 15  2022 file1-bla.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 4015     4015        10716 Feb 15  2022 file2-bla.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 4015     4015          163 Feb 15  2022 file2-bla.txt
```

If I try to use `-i .listing` (or even if I rename .listing to list.txt and use `-i list.txt`) I get an error saying that the URLs are not valid or something.

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) stipulates that

> **LIST (LIST)** This command causes a list to be sent from the server to the passive DTP.  If the pathname specifies a directory or other
> group of files, the server should transfer a list of files in the
> specified directory.  If the pathname specifies a file then the server
> should send current information on the file.  A null argument implies
> the user's current working or default directory.  The data transfer is
> over the data connection in type ASCII or type EBCDIC. (The user must
> ensure that the TYPE is appropriately ASCII or EBCDIC). Since the
> information on a file may vary widely from system to system, this
> information may be hard to use automatically in a program, but may be
> quite useful to a human user.

Observe that it does not impose formal requirement what exactly will be returned.

```
drwxr-xr-x    3 4015     4015        16384 Dec 14 21:23 .
drwxr-xr-x    4 4015     4015         4096 Dec 14 21:23 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 4015     4015          327 Feb 15  2022 file1-bla.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 4015     4015        10716 Feb 15  2022 file2-bla.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 4015     4015          163 Feb 15  2022 file2-bla.txt
```

This looks akin to output of [`ls -lah`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls) command, if you are interested in using that to form URL list acceptable by `wget` then you should take last column (excluding `.` and `..`) and prefix them with URL of FTP server, if that URL is `ftp://ftp.example.com` and you got list as above then your list of URLs should look as follows

```
ftp://ftp.example.com/file1-bla.txt
ftp://ftp.example.com/file2-bla.txt
ftp://ftp.example.com/file3-bla.txt
```